# Updating values row by row using if condition in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to achieve below using pandas dataframe. If the value in col3 is "epic", get the corresponding value in col2 and fill this value into subsequent rows for col2 until the value in col3 is epic, then repeat the same.

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let us do

```
df.col2 = df.col2.where(df.col2.str.contains('fv')).ffill()
```

Update

```
df.col2 = df.col2.where(df.col3=='epic').ffill()
```

Comment: @prashant , you can use the same logic for your updated question - `df.col2 = df.col2.where(df.col3=='epic').ffill()`

Comment: @ggaurav than you for your help , please feel free to update it